# Ignoring Validators

Tags: javascript, asp.net, jquery-ui

I have a page where I use `Javascript` and a `<input>` button to hide the ability to add a new user to my database.  To ensure that people enter in accurate info, I have added validators which works great.  The issue, is that I also have a `GridView` and a search facility on this page and because I use `Javascript` to hide it, no click events will trigger because those textboxes attached to the validators don't have correct data in them.  Is there a way to get it to ignore the validation unless the above button has been clicked?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote this and had another crack at Google.  My issue was that I could add `CausesValidation="False"` to the `ASP:BUTTON` control which worked, but I was using HTML to generate the Add User `button` instead of `ASP.NET`.  Since I was using `JQueryUI`, I found it easier to search how to change from `<input>` to `<asp:button>` controls which I did by changing the javascript from:

```
$("#button").click(function () {
```

to:

```
$("input[id$='AddButton']").click(function () {
```

If I understand it correctly, `<asp:button>` is rendered into HTML as `input[id=...` etc.  Adding in `$` meant that that the script applied to any `<asp:button>` that ended in `AddButton`.  I needed this since I had a few Search buttons on this page hidden in other `Views` and still wanted a consistent naming structure on the page.  The alternative was to use the `^` symbol instead which would apply the script where `AddButton` is at the start of the `ID`.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting [validation group](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227424%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) on that set of fields you want to validate. This should make the validators work only on that set of controls and no other.
Set the validation group on all input controls, validation controls and submit button.